# componentDidUpdate isn't recognising state change

Tags: reactjs

When `supplier._id` changes, the `componentDidUpdate` doesn't recognise the update. Is this because it's nested? What am I missing here?

Path: `React.js`

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    supplier: {
      _id: '',
      name: ''
    }
  };
  this.handleUpdateForm = this.handleUpdateForm.bind(this);
}    


componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
      const { supplier } = this.state;
    
      if (prevState.supplier._id !== supplier._id) {
        console.log('Supplier id changed');
      }
    }
    
    handleUpdateForm(fieldsToUpdate, inputName, inputValue) {
      let { supplier, suppliers } = this.state;
    
      if (fieldsToUpdate === 'supplierFields') {
        if (inputName === 'supplier_id') {
          const selectedSupplier =
            inputName === 'supplier_id'
              ? suppliers.find((supplier) => supplier._id === inputValue)
              : null;
    
          supplier = Object.assign(supplier, selectedSupplier);
        } else {
          supplier._id = inputName === 'name' ? '' : supplier._id;
    
          supplier = Object.assign(supplier, {
            [inputName]: inputValue
          });
        }
      }
    
      this.setState({
        supplier
      });
    }
```

Comment: Could we have the code for how the original state looks?

Comment: @lanxion updated.

Comment: Looks like you are directly mutating react state, a major anti-pattern.

Comment: @DrewReese can you explain a little more. I'm not following.

Comment: In `supplier = Object.assign(supplier, selectedSupplier);`, `supplier` is the state reference. You "merge" `selectedSupplier` into that referenced object. This mutates the state object, `supplier`. `Object.assign` returns the target object, which you save back to `supplier`, and then update state. The object reference for `supplier` *never* changes.

Comment: @DrewReese actually no. he uses object destructuring so that is not actually a reference. His error lies in the fact that he just sets the `supplier` property as state whereas he is supposed to merge the `supplier` in his state with the `supplier` object.

Comment: @lanxion `this.state.supplier` is **most certainly** a reference to a state object, destructured or not. Please recall that `const { supplier } = this.state` is equivalent to `const supplier = this.state.supplier`.

Comment: @DrewReese Ah right. But wouldn't the setState cause issues as well? Or am I confusing syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issue - State Mutation

In `supplier = Object.assign(supplier, selectedSupplier);`, `supplier` is the state reference. You "merge" `selectedSupplier` into that referenced object. This mutates the state object, `supplier`. `Object.assign` returns the target object, which you save back to `supplier`, and then update state. The object reference for `supplier` *never* changes.

## Solution - Shallow copy `supplier` state *then* update

```
handleUpdateForm(fieldsToUpdate, inputName, inputValue) {
  let { supplier, suppliers } = this.state;

  if (fieldsToUpdate === 'supplierFields') {
    if (inputName === 'supplier_id') {
      const selectedSupplier =
        inputName === 'supplier_id'
          ? suppliers.find((supplier) => supplier._id === inputValue)
          : null;

      if (selectedSupplier) {
        supplier = {
          ...supplier, // <-- shallow copy existing state
          ...selectedSupplier, // <-- merge new supplier data
        };
      }
    } else {
      supplier = {
        ...supplier, // <-- shallow copy existing state
        _id: inputName === 'name' ? '' : supplier._id // <-- update property
        [inputName]: inputValue, // <-- merge input update
      };
    }
  }

  this.setState({
    supplier
  });
}
```

Comment: Legend! Great explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the issue lies in how you are setting the state and how you are extracting the values of the state. Since you are using

```
this.setState({
    supplier
  });
```

you are not merging the state with your `supplier` property. So your state is bound to look like this after using `setState`:

```
state = {
  _id: "XXXXXXXXX",
  name: "XXXXXXXX",
  supplier:{
    _id: '',
    _name: ''
  }
}
```

So, in order to fix this, you should change your `setState` to immutably set state on the `supplier` property like:

```
this.setState({
        supplier: {...supplier}
      });
```

The main thing to remember is, `setState` merges whatever changes you put in for a property with the rest of the state.

Comment: this isn't the answer.

Comment: what do you mean? Just change your `setState` to what I have put in the last code snippet and it will start working

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in this part of code

```
 supplier = Object.assign(supplier, {
        [inputName]: inputValue
 });
```

Object.assign takes the first parameter as target and the rest are sources, means 1st parameter object reference will be taken so you're updating the supplier object directly and that's why it's not calling componentDidUpdate. try this -

```
 supplier = Object.assign({}, supplier, {
        [inputName]: inputValue
 });
```

By above snippet a new object will be created